# Problem with WebGL build in Unity in Building Library\Bee\artifacts\WebGL\build\debug_WebGL_wasm\build.js

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, webgl

The project stopped building, constantly giving an error

> Building Library\Bee\artifacts\WebGL\build\debug_WebGL_wasm\build.js failed with output:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 3571, in <module>
> sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 3564, in main
> ret = run(args)
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 1082, in run
> phase_post_link(options, wasm_target, wasm_target, target)
> File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 2400, in phase_post_link
> phase_emscript(options, in_wasm, wasm_target, memfile)
> File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emcc2.py", line 2428, in phase_emscript
> emscripten.run(in_wasm, wasm_target, final_js, memfile)
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emscripten.py", line 830, in run
> emscript(in_wasm, out_wasm, outfile_js, memfile, shared.DEBUG)
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emscripten.py", line 308, in emscript
> glue, forwarded_data = compile_settings()
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\emscripten.py", line 178, in compile_settings
> cwd=path_from_root('src'), env=env)
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 216, in run_js_tool
> return check_call(command, *args, **kw).stdout
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 202, in check_call
> return run_process(cmd, *args, **kw)
> File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.24f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 97, in run_process
> ret = subprocess.run(cmd, check=check, input=input, *args, **kw)
> File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\subprocess.py", line 474, in run
> File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\subprocess.py", line 926, in communicate
> File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 52658: character maps to <undefined>

Errors on build

[image: unity-screenshoot]

I deleted the Bee, and then the Lib folder, tried to run it on my 2021.3.11 version, then updated to 2021.3.24. Changed some build settings. And still this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand what exactly was the problem, but most likely the error was in the dll import line of the external method. It turned out to find out after more than 10 builds, deleting and adding scripts, and then changing the same ill-fated script
It was built without this line, but not with. And after clearing and writing it again, after looking and nothing-wrong-founding in external js method, it suddenly worked

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting non-ASCI symbols from external files in my project (deleting Russian comments in the jslib file in my case).
Version of Unity: 2022.3.10f1

Answer (score 0):

I found what happened with the Bee issue. If you use any package or API script that includes [DllImport("__Internal")], you need to have same name .jslib file that you called. The file icon in Unity is just like a piece of puzzle.